# How do I make a form's Choice Field values show the actual values on a page instead of numbers?

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

There is a field (`categories`) in my form (`NewListing`) that should has 4 values that can be selected in a form on one of my pages. However, when I want to show which value was selected I get a number instead of the value.

The values are:

- New
- Refurbished
- Opened
- Used

So if `New` was selected earlier, when this value is shown on another page it is shown as `1` instead of `New`.

How do I fix this?

models.py:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    ...
    condition = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

forms.py:

```
condition_choices = (
    (1, 'New'),
    (2, 'Refurbished'),
    (3, 'Opened'),
    (4, 'Used'),
)

class NewListing(forms.Form):
    ...
    condition = forms.ChoiceField(choices=condition_choices, widget=forms.Select(attrs={
        'class': 'condition',
    }))
```

html: (irrelevant but shows where it would be used - it selected on another page though - this works fine)

```
<div class="condition">
    <p> Condition: <strong> {{ listing.condition }} </strong></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the elements in the tuple with [human-friendly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#choices) values.

```
CONDITION_CHOICES = [
    ('NEW', 'New'),
    ('REF', 'Refurbished'),
    ('OPE', 'Opened'),
    ('USE', 'Used'),
]
```